# Open accordion panel from another page and scroll down to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I have an accordion on a page which looks like this by default (`www.sitename.com/faq`)

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" href="#question-one" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">What is blah?</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="question-one" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Lorem ipsum
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- more questions below -->
</div>
```

From the home page, I need to insert a link that leads to a certain question.
So if for example I want to see question-one, I would set the link to `href='www.sitename.com/faq#question-one'`

But since it's the panel body that has that ID, it wouldn't scroll to that section unless I open the panel first and reenter the url.

I was wondering if there is a way I can make the panel open and scroll down to that section. Maybe using Javascript or jQuery? (Which I'm not familiar with.) This is how it looks like when the panel is opened, if it helps:

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" href="#question-one" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">What is blah?</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="question-one" class="panel-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
        <div class="panel-body">
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- more questions below -->
</div>
```

Note: I can't modify the HTML of the faq page. It's generated from a separate source.

Edit: The css codes were too long so I think it's just best to take a screenshot of how it looks like.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code (`css` in this case) so we can at least recreate the accordian

Comment: Hello please see my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Oh right, sorry. I think it automatically tagged this as PHP since the last draft on my account had PHP codes. Sorry about that, I'll edit the tags now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `active` property of accordion. Following codePen depicts the same. For demo purpose I have passed `2` as active accordion. You can test it by changing query parameter's value.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/rajesh_dixit/pen/LpKJEP?active=2)

#### Code

```
$("#content").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    active:parseInt(activeAccordion) // This will decide which accordion to open.
});
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not really familiar to js. So should the links be like `www.sitename.com/faq?active=question-one`?

Comment: Yes. But it should be number. You can share value between pages either by passing value in query params or using HTML5 storage or cookies. In any case, you can set index of active accordion

Comment: I tried using this and changing `#content` to `#accordion` as it is the container for the panels and changed the IDs of the questions to numbers and made my url `/faq?active=2` as well but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Try logging `activeAccourdion` value. Also I have used `window.location.search`. Check in `window.location` where your value is appearing and use it